# How to disable the 'Done' button if no radiobutton has been selected

Tags: java, android

I am working on a tasks app, and I have this activity that takes data from the user in the form of radio buttons. However, I don't want the user to exit the activity without filling any radio buttons. How can I go about that? I have been trying to fix this problem since forever, but got nothing yet.

This is the code for my activity :

```java
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SubtaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText etSubtaskName;
  EditText etTaskName;
  Button btnDone, btnCancel;
  RadioGroup radgrpPri, radgrpTime;
  RadioButton radbtnPriHigh, radbtnPriMed, radbtnPriLow, radbtnTimeMore, radbtnTimeMed, radbtnTimeLess;
  boolean priHigh, priMed, priLow, timeMore, timeMed, timeLess;
  String subtaskName;
  String pri;
  String time;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subtask);

    btnDone = findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
    radgrpPri = findViewById(R.id.radgrpPri);
    radgrpTime = findViewById(R.id.radgrpTime);
    radbtnPriHigh = findViewById(R.id.radbtnPriHigh);
    radbtnPriMed = findViewById(R.id.radbtnPriMed);
    radbtnPriLow = findViewById(R.id.radbtnPriLow);
    radbtnTimeMore = findViewById(R.id.radbtnTimeMore);
    radbtnTimeMed = findViewById(R.id.radbtnTimeMed);
    radbtnTimeLess = findViewById(R.id.radbtnTimeLess);
    etSubtaskName = findViewById(R.id.etSubtaskName);
    btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

    btnDone.setEnabled(false);

    priLow = false;
    priMed = false;
    priHigh = false;

    timeMore = false;
    timeMed = false;
    timeLess = false;

    radgrpPri.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        if (radbtnPriHigh.isChecked()) {
          priHigh = true;
          priLow = false;
          priMed = false;
          pri = "h";

        } else if (radbtnPriMed.isChecked()) {
          priHigh = false;
          priLow = false;
          priMed = true;
          pri = "m";

        } else if (radbtnPriLow.isChecked()) {
          priHigh = false;
          priLow = true;
          priMed = false;
          pri = "l";
        } else {
          priLow = true;
          pri = "l";
        }

      }
    });

    radgrpTime.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        if (radbtnTimeMore.isChecked()) {
          timeMore = true;
          timeMed = false;
          timeLess = false;

          time = "more";
        } else if (radbtnTimeMed.isChecked()) {
          timeMore = false;
          timeMed = true;
          timeLess = false;
          time = "med";
        } else if (radbtnTimeLess.isChecked()) {
          timeMore = false;
          timeMed = false;
          timeLess = true;
          time = "less";
        } else {
          timeLess = true;
          time = "less";
        }

      }
    });

    etSubtaskName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        btnDone.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim()));
      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      }
    });

    btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        String name = etSubtaskName.getText().toString().trim();

        Intent intent = new Intent(SubtaskActivity.this, TaskInfo.class);
        intent.putExtra("subtaskName", name);
        intent.putExtra("priHigh", priHigh);
        intent.putExtra("priMed", priMed);
        intent.putExtra("priLow", priLow);
        intent.putExtra("timeMore", timeMore);
        intent.putExtra("timeMed", timeMed);
        intent.putExtra("timeLess", timeLess);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        SubtaskActivity.this.finish();

        // THIS IS WHERE I SAVE THE DATA IN ROOM

      }
    });

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        etSubtaskName.setText("");
        radgrpPri.clearCheck();
        radgrpTime.clearCheck();
        finish();

      }
    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to check whether each radio is checked or not like you use the `if(){}else` condition

First, use all the radio buttons in XML and in your activity file

```
radgrpTime.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
          checkedId = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
          radio_button = findViewbyId(checkedId);
          //RadioButton radio_button;
      }
    });

// to check if any radio button is selected use

if(radio_button != null){
//it is checked
}else{
// not checked
}
```

Comment: If you want to assign any values to specific radio button selection than you can use a switch case and assign the values according to selection.